# what is a string for programming it seems complex - example

Tags: iphone

i have been trying to figure this out for days - what exactly is a string

it seems to be a complex statement or something

how do you use a string in programming

it is some logicial thing

what would be an example of using a string
thank you for reading my question. it would be Nice if you answer.

how many lines do you need for it to work

Comment: The exact definition will depend on the language you're using, but it's just a collection of characters.

Comment: A string is just a text.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, a `string` just was an array of the primitive type `char`

Now (at least in **iPhone** - `swift` language - as you mentioned in the question tag) string is just like a primitive type by itself. (I don't sure that's correct for `objective c` too)

And it's already said but it's just a text.